# make createElement a link on the IMG attribute

Tags: javascript

i've created an element in javascript that shows an image:

```
 const image = document.createElement('img');
                        image.setAttribute('class', 'imgGame');
                        image.setAttribute('alt', game.name );
                        image.setAttribute('title', game.name );
                        image.src = game.background_image;
                        card.appendChild(image);
```

now i've tried to add

image.setAttribute('href', mylinkVariable);

or

```
image.href =
```

but i can't make the image a link (target blank and nofollow) to a website.

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: images dont have href attribute

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Attach a `click` event listener to the image which assigns the desired location to `window.location` when the image has been clicked:

```js
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('class', 'imgGame');
image.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';
document.body.appendChild(image);

image.addEventListener('click', () => location = "https://stacksnippets.net")
```

Comment: this actually works but not in a blank page

Comment: @samaBARI What do you mean?

Comment: i want to open the link in target _blank

Comment: solved with window.open instead

Answer (score 2):

wrap the `<img>` with an `<a>` and then add the href to it.

or

```
img.onclick = () => window.location.replace('YOUR URL');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add link to img just wrap with  a(link) tag like this;

```
const card = document.getElementById('card');
const link = document.createElement('a');
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('class', 'imgGame');
image.setAttribute('alt', game.name);
image.setAttribute('title', game.name);
image.src = game.background_image;
link.appendChild(image);
link.setAttribute('href', mylinkVariable);
card.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Comment: this is a sample code, just check whether you've added card div to your html document